# How can I disable and enable a resource route Link in remix-run

Tags: remix.run

Is there a way to disable a Resource route link while the resource is being generated and enabling it after that?

I have a PDF report that gets generated as soon as the user clicks on a Link. So I'm using a resource route that returns the PDF as a ReadableStream with a content-Disposition of attachment.

Here's a a code fragment example:

```js
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  invariant(params.recordID, "Record Id is required!");
  let recordID = params.recordID;

  let reportsService = createReportsService();
  let reportFileStream = await reportsService.getReport(
    recordID
  );

  return new Response(reportFileStream, {
    headers: {
      "Content-disposition": `attachment; filename=report.pdf`,
      "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    },
  });
};
```

I'm using the Link to the resource route this way:

```js
<Link to={reportUrl} reloadDocument >
  Get the Report
</Link>
```

I want the Link to get disabled as soon as the user clicks on it and then re enable it after the report is ready and the user has saved it (or discarded the "save" window).

I can't use `useTransition` hook because `reloadDocument`  disables javascript behavior but I can't find out another way to disable and enable the link.
I can only disable it as soon as the user clicks on it (with a conditional `pointer-events` style controlled by `useState`) but I haven't found a way to detect when the report has been generated and the user has saved it (or discarded the "save" window) so I can re enable the link again.

So any help or hint to find a solution is very much appreciated!

Comment: i'm having the same problem, did you figured out how anything?